# Is it possible to change an enum class variable's specific type without knowing the original enum class?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, metaprogramming

Sorry if the question title is a bit confusing. In my game engine I have the following defined in ResourceIdentifiers.hpp:

```
namespace Textures
{
    enum class Id
    {
        Error = -1,
        Player
    };
}
```

I have lots of similar definitions, for music, fonts, etc etc (every single one has a type called Error). Now in ResourceHolder.hpp I have the following (cut down dramatically of course):

```
template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
class ResourceHolder
{
public:    
    Resource& get(Identifier id);

private:
    Resource& getErrorResource(Identifier id);

    std::map<Identifier, std::unique_ptr<Resource> > m_resourceMap;
};
```

And in ResourceHandler.cpp:

```
template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
Resource& ResourceHolder<Resource, Identifier>::get(Identifier id)
{
    auto found = m_resourceMap.find(id);

    if (found == m_resourceMap.end())
    {
        return getErrorResource(id);
    }

    return *found->second;
}
```

The meat of my question lies within getErrorResource(). Since get() returns a reference to a resource, if a resource that the user's calling for isn't initialized, I want to return an error version of the resource so the program can keep running (in Texture's case, what `id` would want to be is `Textures::Id::Error`). The issue is that I don't want to fill getErrorResource() with a bunch of ifs to correctly set it to Error. Is there a way to figure out what enum class `id` was originally, then set it to its corresponding "Error"?

Comment: `Texture::Id::Error` has to be associated (i.e. deducible at compile time) with a type for that to work. I don't see any such association in your posted code.

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake, edited.

Comment: That edit does nothing to address the issue I raised.

Comment: Then I'm a bit confused on what exactly you meant, I'm sorry.

Comment: What are the template parameters used to instantiate `ResourceHolder`? What's the relationship between those template parameters and `Texture::Id::Error`?